# Where does task_struct get initialized in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there a function that gets called to initialize (at least some) values of `task_struct`? Or is there any other function that gets called upon task (specifically, user-space process) creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the only way to create a new process in Linux is through the `clone()` syscall (or other variants like `fork()`), there is no real function to "create a new task" from scratch, but there sure is a function to *duplicate* an existing task, applying the needed modifications. The function used for this is [`copy_process()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/kernel/fork.c#L1902), which uses [`dup_task_struct()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/kernel/fork.c#L874) to duplicate the associated `struct task_struct`.

There is however one special exception to this rule: the init process (the first process created after booting) is created by the kernel itself (every other process is then created by init or by some child of init through `clone()` + `execve()`). The `task_struct` for the init task is *statically defined* at compile time ([see here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/init/init_task.c#L64)). You can look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744200/how-is-the-init-process-started-in-the-linux-kernel) if you want to know more.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!